# Excel VBA code reads wrong innerHTML code

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am absolutely new in webscraping and have some minor previous VBA knowledge.
I am trying to make a scraper which enters a site makes a search and then scrapes the details of the search. 
I am very annoyed that my scraper can make the search with the given parameters, but after the search is made and the website is loaded, I make a innerHTML read request within VBA and the results are NOT the source code of the new page. So I cannot extract any information because my VBA code does not see the actual webpage html data. Why is that happening? What is the source code that my VBA extracts?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

```
    Public Sub my_scraper()

    Dim my_data1, my_data2 As String
    Dim my_Coll As String

    i = 1



    my_data1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value
    my_data2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value

    my_Coll = profession_hu_scraper(my_data1, my_data2)



    Cells(2, 2).Value = my_Coll



End Sub


Public Function profession_hu_scraper(ByVal my_data1 As String, ByVal my_data2 As String) As String


    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Dim Link As Object
    Dim ElementCol As Object
    Dim erow As Long
    'Dim all_inp_el As Object


    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "https://www.profession.hu/"

        Do While .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            Application.StatusBar = "Loading website..."
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set html = .Document
        Range("A16") = html.DocumentElement.innerHTML




        .Document.getElementById("header_keyword").Value = my_data1
        .Document.getElementById("header_location").Value = my_data2

        Set my_classes = .Document.getElementsByClassName("p2_button_inner")

        For Each my_class In my_classes
            If my_class.getAttribute("value") = "Keresés" Then
                Range("c4") = "Clicked"
                my_class.Click
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next my_class

        Do While .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            Application.StatusBar = "Loading website..."
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set html = .Document
        Range("B16") = html.DocumentElement.innerHTML

     End With
     Set objIE = Nothing
      Application.StatusBar = "Finished"

    'Application.StatusBar = ""
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of struggling I finally was able to find out that the code works OK. The problem was that the max character of a cell is 32k so it could not show the whole html code. 
If you are a beginner watch out for it!

Answer (score -2):

Updated:

```
Public Function profession_Hu_Scraper(myData1 As String, my_data2 As String)
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ie.navigate "https://www.profession.hu/"

    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    Set doc = ie.document
    ws.Range("A16") = doc.getElementById(myData1).innerText
    ws.Activate("B16") = doc.getElementById(mydata2).innerText
    'whatever else you wish to do
End Function
```

Comment: Dear JamTay. Thank your for the script but it does not help me at all. I described in my post that my problem is the following:

Comment: Unfortunatelly this is not the answer I was looking for. Can somebody help please?